# Alternative for virtual template functions

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, polymorphism, virtual

I Have an abstract `UI` class that needs to be able to ask the user for some input.
This function is templated because different things can be asked for.

However, this function must also be virtual because I want derived classes of `UI` to be able to 
provide their own implementations (a `CommandLineUI` will need to behave differently from 
`WebBasedUI`).

```
class UI {
    // ...

    public:
        // ask some input
        template<T>
        virtual T askFor(const std::string& mesg) const = 0;

        // ask but provide default fallback
        template<T>
        virtual T askFor(const std::string& mesg, const T& def) const = 0;
}

class CommandLineUI : UI {
    // ...
    public:
        template<T>
        virtual T askFor(const std::string& mesg) const {
            // implementation details
        }
        template<T>
        virtual T askFor(const std::string& mesg, const T& def) const {
            // implementation details
        }
}
```

The above code will not work however, since a templated method cannot be virtual in C++,
for reasons that go above me.

I read some things about the Visitor pattern or type erasure being able to fix this problem, but I fail to see how. (I tried to translate the examples found in answers to 
similar stack overflow questions but this wasn't successful).

Comment: Template functions cannot be `virtual`.

Comment: The virtual function cannot be a template since the amount of overloads must be known at compile-time. However, if you do a `ui.askFor<not_yet_used_type>()` in code somewhere, the vtable of objects created in a different compilation unit would be missing that entry.

Comment: The problem here is that you are trying to mix runtime and compile-time polymorphy. Why not define a set of supported types? Normally you can get around quite well with a set like int, float, string, datetime, lists of them, dictionaries of them.

Comment: Seems like you didn't really think this design through. How would you implement `CommandLineUI::askFor`? What should happen when I call `ui->askFor<Frobnicator>("Enter frobnicator:")`?

Comment: `askFor` works for everything that can be read of a stream. The problem with writing custom functions for `int`, `double`, `string`, etc. is that the implementation code would be very repetitious and the `askFor` functions are really complicated...

Comment: Wjat is a 'stream', and what are 'things that can be read from them'?  Stresm is used for many abstract and concrete concepts in programming.  Ditto for 'can be read from a stream'.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, the standard is extremely straightforward

> §14.5.2.3) A member function template shall not be virtual. [ *Example:*

```
template <class T> struct AA {
    template <class C> virtual void g(C); // error
    virtual void f(); // OK
};
```

> *— end example* ]

Basically, how would you implement them? What would the vtable look like?

If all you need is a type that is "in-streamable", I'd recommend checking out the [Boost.TypeErasure](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_typeerasure/basic.html) library. It may not exactly solve your problem, but it's pretty neat. You'll need something like:

```
using Inputable = any<
    mpl::vector<
        copy_constructible<>,
        typeid_<>,
        istreamable<>
    >
>;

virtual Inputable askFor(const std::string& mesg) const = 0;
```

Probably something more involved than that, I've only played around with that library but it makes it possible to have a virtual "template" member function as long as you clearly define what it is you need your template type to do. (Note that there's also an `any_cast` so the caller knows what type he wants to get, he can always cast the result to it.)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, I would advice to give the interface a series of virtual functions for a limited set of types you want to support. In derived classes you can forward the call of each overridden function to a single template function that implements the desired functionality.